# Run WinSat Command C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to run cmd winsat -drive c programmatically

The code below is only returning "Windows System Assessment Tool" the first line of the output but is not letting the winsat run and return the rest of the output

I am looking for the entire output to be returned shown here

[image]

The code I am using is this

```
public string RunAndOutput(object command)
{
    var procStartInfo =
        new ProcessStartInfo("winsat", "/c " + "-drive c");

    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    var proc = new Process();

    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
    proc.Start();

    string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    proc.WaitForExit(); // Wait for everything to finish

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to wait for the process to exit using [WaitForExit()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
public string RunAndOutput(object command)
{
    var procStartInfo =
        new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    var proc = new Process();

    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
    proc.Start();

    string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    proc.WaitForExit(); // Wait for everything to finish

    return result;
}
```

Comment: this is returning just the first line as well